# Issue with Hash in chart creation

Tags: powershell, charts

I am trying to create chart by [`Get-CorpChart-FullEdition`](https://ammarhasayen.com/2013/11/25/charts-and-powershell-draw-them-now/) script, which I found very good in chart creation.

On the website I found below instruction.

> So now, all what you have to do is to give the `$Cities` array to the function as `-Data` parameter, and supply the `-Obj_Key` parameter as "City_Name", and `-Obj_Value` as "City_Population"

I created a hash like this:

```
$active_inactive = @{}
$red = 15
$orange = 25
$active_inactive['active']= $red
$active_inactive['inactive'] = $orange

. "D:\Auto\Get-Corpchart-LightEdition.ps1" -data $active_inactive -obj_key "Name" -obj_value "Value" -filepath "c:\chart1.png" -type pie
```

Data in `$active_inactive`:

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
inactive                       7
active                         3
```

Problem is I am getting a blank chart1.png file. It seems like issue with my hashtable.

Can anybody advise me if I am creating the hashtable properly as described above or not?

Comment: Does is work if you do this: `-data $active_inactive.GetEnumerator()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted to use a hashtable I think you can if you call the `.GetEnumarator()` method

> which effectively sends each entry in the hash table across the pipeline as a separate object.

```
. "D:\Auto\Get-Corpchart-LightEdition.ps1" -data $active_inactive.GetEnumerator() -obj_key "Name" -obj_value "Value" -filepath "c:\chart1.png" -type pie
```

Looking at the code for the light edition of the script the parameter is expecting an `[array]` and not a hashtable.

You would be better of creating your own custom objects from that hashtable's 
data depending on how complex your date would get.

```
[pscustomobject]@{
    State="Active"
    Value=15
},[pscustomobject]@{
    State="Inactive"
    Value=25
}
```

Tonnes of ways to do this more effectively so the above is just an example.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Comment: I am trying to create array of active =15, inactive = 20 but it is not working. Could you explain bit more.

Answer (score 2):

`-data` expects an array of objects, not a hashtable.